# how to save specific field in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

here is my code

```
public function settings(){
$this->loadModel('Userinfo');

    $helpers = array('TimeZoneHelper');
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $id = $this->Auth->User('idUser');


 $data =  $this->request->data['Userinfo']['timezone'];
 $this->Userinfo->save($data,array(
     'conditions' => array('Userinfo.User_id' => $id))));

}
```

i have a field name **timezone** in my **userinfo** table .. which i want to update .. i dont know how can i specifically update the single field in Cakephp as i am new in Cakephp ..i am doing this but dont know why it isn't working ...well when i debug the **$data** .. the data is coming fine ..
in database the datatype of timezone is "time"

Comment: You aren't showing a lot of effort here - There are 10s if not 100s of duplicate questions of this kind of thing - and it's also covered by [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) and the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html). And it looks like you're just making code up (passing conditions to save? where have you seen that?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set you models id:

`$this->Userinfo->id = $id;`

Then, use the savefield function to save a specific field:

`$this->Userinfo->saveField('timezone', 'UTC');`

Good luck further on cakePhp!